# File Viewer for all extention for asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have archive website application, this software for archive all document a company. Admin this software upload any extension in this software like AutoCAD, images(png,gif,...), pdf file, etc, I want when user select a file show this file in viewer in browser, But I do not know what tool to use, please help me, thanks all.

Comment: Your question is very broad, I suggest you begin here http://asp.net-tutorials.com/controls/file-upload-control/

Comment: @ BigBadOwl : i uploded file and save file in database, but for show i have problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an image from every file uploaded. Show that to end users.

Answer (score 1):

There is no tool or component that will allow you to show all propriety file formats that exists today.

For every pariticular file format that you wont to support you must have code that understands that format, AFAIK component suite for ASP.NET that have biggest number of supported file formats is Aspose.NET :

http://www.aspose.com/.net/total-component.aspx